# Use one combined property in knex to query two separate columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I want to query items from Postgres database with knex. In the database, I have two separate columns `first_name` and `last_name`, but I need to compare them both to a single value which is formatted `"last_name, first_name"`.

How can I combine those two fields in a `.where` clause?

For example:

```js
const res = await Database.knex
.select()
.from(`${DB_SCHEMA}.t_contacts as contacts`)
.where({
   'contacts.email': email
})
.andWhere({
   'contacts.status': 'ACTIVE'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution was to split the given value by ", " and then have a list of firstNames and lastNames, and then have two where queries for two fields.

```
const firstNames = search.names.map((name) => name.split(', ')[1]);
const lastNames = search.names.map((name) => name.split(', ')[0]);

const res = await Database.knex
.select()
.from(`${DB_SCHEMA}.t_contacts as contacts`)
.whereIn(
   'contacts.first_name', firstNames
)
.whereIn(
   'contacts.last_name', lastNames
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`whereRaw()`](https://knexjs.org/guide/query-builder.html#whereraw) to combine the columns before comparing to your value:

```js
const res = await Database.knex
.select()
.from(`${DB_SCHEMA}.t_contacts as contacts`)
.whereRaw("concat(first_name,', ',last_name) = ?", [your_combined_value]);
```

You could also split your value and compare its parts to their corresponding columns. You can even [let PostgreSQL handle the split](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.7.2.2.32.1.1.1)

```js
const res = await Database.knex
.select()
.from(`${DB_SCHEMA}.t_contacts as contacts`)
.whereRaw("first_name = split_part(? ,', ',1)", [your_combined_value]);
```